# Jenkins: Add PreBuild step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I wanted to add a pre build step where, I want to trigger a specific Jenkins job and wait for it to complete before starting to go on with the current job.

For eg:
Workspace A
Workspace B

If Workspace B is started due to git push, I wanted Workspace A to be triggered first and then Workspace B.

Is this feasible?

I tried with parameterised plugin and Jenkins pipeline but both appear to be good only for post build action continuation from Workspace A.

Answer (score 2):

With [jenkins-pipeline](/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline), you are free to define your "flow". Using the `build` step, you can trigger another job whenever you like, i.e., before you do your "build".

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand, I have a pipeline currently set in Jenkins and also I have given the intial job as Workspace A. However, when i trigger Workspace B, it does not trigger workspace A before starting Workspace B.
What I wanted is a pre build workspace A and then start WorkspaceB on triggering WorkspaceB

Comment: You don't build workspaces, you run jobs. Sure, job B will start first, but as long as it first calls job A and then continues with its "own" tasks, what's the problem?

Comment: jobB depends on the artificats of jobA and hence, it has to wait till the workspaceA completes and then proceed

Comment: Workspace name was just an example, I aint building workspace.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Achieved using build step itself. Damn! I was struggling for this since yesterday. I just have to add a build call on other projects and drag it over the execute shell, so that this executes first and JobB waits for the completion of JobA

Comment: Okay! So this appears to be good but since I am blocking the JobA until the downstream JobB completes, now triggering JobA from JobB is blocked since, JobA sees JobB already running and hence wont start while JobB waits for JobA for ever to complete. 

Please throw light :(

Comment: Is there a way to make, initial job as JobA no matter which job starts? I am basically depending on a push in the bitbucket which will trigger JobB but JobB to run requires JobA to send artifacts. Since, we want to know which artifact is verified in the JobB, we make sure JobA does not send any more artifacts until JobB completes and hence blocking downstream. Would be glad to know a way to trigger upstrema build first even if downstream build receives git push

Answer (score 0):

Use the [build step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/):

```
stages
{
    stage('Schedule some jobs')
    {
        steps
        {
          echo 'Scheduling:'
          build( [job:"myjob1", wait: false, propagate: false] )
          build( [job:"myjob2", wait: false, propagate: false] )
          build( [job:"myjob3", wait: false, propagate: false] )
        }
    }
```